# Global Assembly Cache redirection

Tags: .net, windows, .net-assembly, gac, assembly-binding-redirect

I have two DLLs with same assembly version but Assembly File Version. One DLL is present in the gac, i want every app referencing to the DLL present in GAC to get redirected to the other assembly. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry you can't. You either have to put the assembly you want to redirect to in the GAC or  put it alongside each exe that is referencing the old one. Then you can use a [publisher policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz32563a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), change all app.configs or the machine.config. You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).